# Refresh Animated Plot with Tkinter Scale Widget

Tags: python, numpy, tkinter, matplotlib-animation

I'm working on an interactive pseudo-standing wave demo, and I'm at a bit of an impasse. Essentially, the goal of this project is to recreate a variant of Melde's experiment, wherein a string is driven by an oscillator on one end with the other end connected to a pulley at a 90 degree angle. In the physical version of this experiment, one would add lead shot pellets to a cup hanging from this pulley, increasing the tension in the string until a standing wave is formed.

This project isn't truly a standing wave simulation, as I'm not numerically solving the wave equation with the necessary boundary conditions; rather, I'm generating an incident sine wave and a 'reflected' sine wave. Here, the incident wave can be tuned such that the wave vectors between the two waves match up, producing a standing wave. My goal is to be able to tune this wave by adjusting the number of lead shot pellets dropped into the cup via a scale widget through Tkinter. In other words, I want to be able to adjust the slider shown in the screenshot below and have the (animated) wave update accordingly.

[image]

I've found a few somewhat related questions on this very forum, but they all seem to be related to updating a still plot with the movement of the slider, or animating the slider itself. In my case, the wave plot is already animated - already moving in time, and I want to refresh the animation itself whenever the slider is adjusted. I know that I need to command the scale widget to call on a function, but I'm not sure how to do this while still preserving the animation function already present in the code. Ultimately, I want to be able to control the parameter N (towards the top of the code below) using the scale widget, with the animated plot updating accordingly.

```
import matplotlib.pylab as plot
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.animation as animation
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg
import tkinter as tk

h = 3                           #define nth harmonic
kval = np.pi*h/100              #wave vector from nth harmonic (1/cm)
mu = 0.001                      #linear string mass density (g/cm)
g = 980                         #gravitational acceleration (cm/s/s)
N = 50                          #number of lead shot pellets
m = N*0.01216                   #total mass of lead shot pellets (g)
A = 0.15                        #wave amplitude
omega = 120                     #angular wave frequency
k1 = omega*np.sqrt(mu/(m*g))    #wave vector for initial wave (1/cm)
k2 = k1*k1/kval                 #wave vector for 'reflected' wave (1/cm)

fig = plot.Figure()

x = np.linspace(0,100,500)

def animate(i):
    line.set_ydata(A*np.sin(k1*x+omega*i) + A*np.sin(k2*x - omega*i))
    return line,

main = tk.Tk()

#background text
intro = tk.Label(main,text='Add lead shot to produce a standing wave.').grid(column=0,row=0)

canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(fig, master=main)
canvas.get_tk_widget().grid(column=0,row=1)

ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax.set_xlim(0,100)
ax.set_ylim(-2,2)

line, = ax.plot(x, A*np.sin(k1*x) + A*np.sin(k2*x))
anim = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, interval=50, blit=False)

horizontal = tk.Scale(main, from_=50, to=300, length=400, orient='horizontal').grid(column=0,row=2)

main.mainloop()
```

Any suggestions are greatly appreciated! I'm very new to using Tkinter, so I'm likely just missing something obvious.

Comment: Since you already have an animation running, you don't actually need to do anything in response to the slider being moved.  Just get the current slider value in your `animate()` function, and use it as appropriate in your update calculation.  Note that in order to do this, you need a name by which to refer to the slider.  `horizontal` is currently just `None`, the result of the `.grid()` call rather than the widget itself.

Comment: Thank you so much, that worked perfectly! Much simpler than I was fearing the solution might be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply getting the current slider value within the animate function itself worked perfectly, as user [jasonharper](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1709364/jasonharper) stated.